# Functoriality of base change morphisms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Consider a commutative diagram of morphisms of schemes:

$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
X_2 & \xrightarrow{j_2} & Y_2 \\
f'\downarrow  & & \downarrow f \\ 
X_1 & \xrightarrow{j_1} & Y_1
\end{array} $$

Here the vertical arrows are proper and the horizontal arrows are open immersions.

In SGA 4, Expose VIII, Section 5 ([see p. 189 of this pdf](http://www.normalesup.org/~forgogozo/SGA4/tomes/tome3.pdf)), a morphism between functors $D^{+}_\text{tor}(X_2) \rightarrow D^{+}_\text{tor}(Y_1)$

$$\theta_{21}: {j_{1}}_{!}Rf'_* \rightarrow Rf_*{j_{2}}_{!} $$

is defined. (It is an isomorphism.)

Now, given a commutative diagram of schemes (with vertical arrows proper and horizontal arrows open immersions):
$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
X_3 & \xrightarrow{j_3} & Y_3 \\
g'\downarrow  & & \downarrow g \\ 
X_2 & \xrightarrow{j_2} & Y_2 \\
f'\downarrow  & & \downarrow f \\ 
X_1 & \xrightarrow{j_1} & Y_1
\end{array} $$

Let $\theta_{21}$, $\theta_{32}$, $\theta_{31}$ be the morphisms for the lower, upper, and composed squares respectively.

There are two morphisms ${j_{1}}_{!}R(f' \circ g')_* \rightarrow R(f \circ g)_*{j_{3}}_{!}$: The first one is $\theta_{31}$, and the second one is the composition:

$${j_{1}}_{!}R(f' \circ g')_* \cong({j_1}_!Rf'_*)Rg'_* \xrightarrow{\theta_{21} \circ Rg'_*} Rf_*{j_2}_!Rg'_* \xrightarrow{Rf_* \circ \theta_{32}} Rf_*Rg_*{j_3}_! \cong R(f \circ g)_*{j_{3}}_{!}$$

***Question:*** Are these two morphisms equal? If so, why?

Actually I am looking for a *completely detailed proof* that this is true, if it is true. When I try to check it myself, I get lost. Perhaps it is actually easy, and I'm missing something?